# Syntax Error (Missing Operator) when exporting from VBA Excel to Access

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am trying to make my code output from an excel spreadsheet to an access database, however the code always results in a syntax error (missing expression) in query expression "Road Cost". It is supposed to cycle through a selection of cells and copy those into the database.

```
Sub export()
'
' export Macro
Dim rs As Object
Dim cn As Object
Dim SQL As String
Dim columncount As Integer
Dim Value, id As Integer
Dim Criteria As String
Dim haha As Range

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
accessfile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Engi340 P1.accdb"
cn.Open "provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data source =" & accessfile
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set haha = Range("J21")
id = 1
Do While id < 4
 hoho = haha.Offset(id - 1, 0)
 hehe = haha.Offset(id - 1, 1)
 SQL = "UPDATE Results SET Criteria=" & hoho & ", Value=" & hehe & " WHERE ID=" & id & ";"
 Set rs = cn.Execute(SQL)
 id = id + 1
 Loop
 End Sub
```

Update: in the access database ID is a number, criteria is a short text, and value is a number. Both numbers are long integers.

Comment: you may be missing quote marks in the string when `SQL= ...` gets evaluated. please post what you think is the value of SQL after the evaluation

Comment: Where do you think I need to add quote marks? If I put them at the beginning, it gives a compile error syntax error. Everywhere else my quotes are even.

Comment: quotes around  the value of `hoho` and the value of `hehe` and the value of `id` inside the SQL string ... that is why i asked you to post what the SQL string should look like

Comment: aww heck .... try this `SQL = "UPDATE Results SET Criteria=""" & hoho & """, Value=""" & hehe & """ WHERE ID=""" & id & """";"`

Comment: Now it says expected end of query and then gives compile error: Syntax error.

Comment: The final part of @jsotola's code should be `& """;"`

Comment: Try `SQL = "UPDATE Results SET Criteria='" & hoho & "', Value=" & hehe & " WHERE ID=" & id & ";"` (and, if that doesn't work, try `SQL = "UPDATE [Results] SET [Criteria]='" & hoho & "', [Value]=" & hehe & " WHERE [ID]=" & id & ";"` just in case any of those field names are reserved words)

Comment: That worked, Thank you so much. Apparently one of the headings was a reserved word.

Comment: Yup, `VALUE` is a keyword, so it should be avoided as a field name